# Salesforce mobilesdk iOS with push?

Tags: ios4, push-notification, salesforce

Has anyone worked with Salesforce mobilesdk for iOS and implemented push? Need some guidance? First of all are the services available in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Salesforce iOS SDK is just libraries to facilitate communications (via the REST API) and oAuth with Salesforce. For everything else you use the standard Apple libraries, so you'd use those to deal with push notifications. One thing I can recommend with regards to the Salesforce iOS stuff is to clone the git repository over using the package published on the developer blog, changes are still being made and so you need to stay up to date to avoid breakages.

Afraid I can't comment on generating push notifications on the Salesforce side, but I'd hazard a guess that you'll need to integrate with a third party or custom application via web services to achieve this.

Comment: From the Salesforce side, you could use the new Streaming API to push updates to query results. See http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Ios SDK helps in communication to salesaforce using REST APIs, to push and pull the data, rest all the things are done as normal push app does.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile SDK can help in login, oAuth and to communicate with the SFDC objects. You need to implement Push Notification Services as any other iOS application does.

To post the notificaitons for any events from Salesforce you can use Urban Airship or Streaming API.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Push_Notifications_for_Salesforce_Mobile_Apps_with_Urban_Airship